# What is a good strategy for taking a facebook holiday?

Tags: facebook

I'd like to change my life from using facebook ALL the time, to never really checking it. I do not have the self control to do this so, so I want to change my password etc.

I'd still like:

- Receive event invitations
- Have an automatic replier to people who PM me (or a way that they know I'm not using facebook etc).
- e.g change my middle name to 'on-fb-holyday' or something, or my profile / cover photo to (on facebook holiday)
- I don't care about anything else!

Any ideas?

Comment: Start blogging/tweeting?

Comment: Adjust your profile like you said, add a post saying you won't be using facebook for a while, enable invitations notification to your email, log out, close your browser.  go to C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\ and open the file 'hosts' with notepad (you might need special permissions for this). Add a new line `127.0.0.1 facebook.com` and another `127.0.0.1 m.facebook.com` and another `127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com`. Now open command prompt and type `ipconfig /flushdns` and press enter. Open your browser, as you can see, facebook is now gone. Undo the changes to the hosts file to undo this block.

Comment: Receive event invites - you can set to receive email / SMS notification when you get invited. Automatic replier - again set to receive email / SMS for received messages. Change your name - fairly straightforward. If you have a best mate, get THEM to change your password, and don't tell you. Or generate a random 10-12 digit password (say using lastpass) and then tell Lastpass to forget the entry.

Answer (score 2):

You have answered yourself, change your name to `not using facebook`

Change your profile pic and cover photo to `you can reach me on user@example.com`